# Sticky footer is causing content to fall below fold

Tags: android, html, ios, css, mobile

Running into an issue mainly on iOS(surprise) My  footer is a sticky footer, while it is working according to how a sticky footer works the problem is that content falls below the footer, mainly the image of the lady.

I've tried several workarounds from spanning the image into the background, combining it into the footer, different positioning and nothing seems to work. Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious here?

I replaced the original image. Move your browser vertically all the way in the fiddle and you will see the content fall below. Also I tried using `position:fixed` on `.quote` but that causes problems with the soft keyboard on iOS and Android.

[image]

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/6u5AJ/

```
    .foot_c {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-y:hidden;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .footer {
      background: #3c78bc;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 8px 0 5px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    .footerbg {
      background: url(images/bgfoot.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      min-height: 90px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }

  <div class="bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
      </div>
          <div class="column">
              <form id="myform" action="buttons.html" method="POST">
                  <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Enter your Zip"></input>
                  <input type="submit" value="Compare"></input>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="quote">
            <img src="images/quote_lady.png" alt="quote_lady">
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="foot_c">
        <div class="footerbg">
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
              <p><a href="tel:1-(999)-999-9999">Your Guide to Auto Insurance Quotes!</a></p>
              <div class="phone">
                <img src="images/phone.png" alt="phone">
                <h3><a href="tel:1-(999)-999-9999"><span>Call Now</span><strong>1-(999) 999-9999</strong></a></h3><br />
              </div>
              <br><a href="terms.php" style="font-size: xx-small; text-decoration: underline">Terms of Use</a>  |  <a href="privacy.php" style="font-size: xx-small; text-decoration: underline">Privacy Policy</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hey, so do you want the footer to stay after the image and always at the bottom? Also, the footer should always be on the screen?

Comment: Yes, the footer always need to be on screen, not matter what phone size. The footer also has to be at the bottom at all times.

Comment: I posted something the might help you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question any more.

Comment: There is no reason to delete a question when it is fixed - Stack Overflow is a place where people should be able to learn from other people's questions.

Comment: Please do not delete the question. Other people may run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this helps,

For both version I change your HTML a little bit, remove the foot-bg, I didn`t understand why you had that, and merge your background options hex color with img url.

### Check this fiddle to POSITION:RELATIVE

http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/6u5AJ/2/

### Check this fiddle to POSITION:FIXED

http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/yXRS8/1/

On FIXED version I added a padding-bottom to the body make sure all content will appear:

```
padding-bottom:90px // = height of the footer
```

Let me kwnow!

Comment: Footerbg was the hill background, but its enclosed in the footer so it won't affect either fiddle. I'll try these out and let you know. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Fixed does work, but unfortunately since it's not statically placed there it causes the rest of the content to scroll which won't work. Essentially the footer will always be bottom no matter what phone size. And the rest of content above. Of course the display of content will vary per size of phone.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually like to do this is by having the footer one of two children of a parent that has `min-height:100` and `position:relative`. The first child of this is your content container and the second, obviously, is the footer. The content container is made to be 100% height of the parent and given a bottom padding large enough to keep it's content out of the footer which is absolutely positioned at the bottom of the parent.

Modified your example to show this. I didn't remove much of your CSS so it may not be clear where the changes are but basically the 'bg' div seemed to be your main container so I made that `min-height: 100%` (remembering to define 100% heights on all it's parents else it won't work) and then gave the 'container' div the 100% height and padding at the bottom big enough to show the footer.

Hope this is clear enough.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredkhan/6u5AJ/3/

Comment: The sticky footer works fine, but what about not having it fall below the screen on any phone?

Comment: Meant to say not having the footer fall below the screen since it is positioned relative.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read your comments thoroughly enough before posting this, sorry! The position fixed solution on Mattos post does what you want on some mobile browsers but, as your aware, some simply won't accept fixed positioning because it's not great practice on mobile (clutters screen). If you're dead set on having it fixed in place, an alternative is to have the content container have overflow scroll and, for example, 80% height. and then give the footer 20% height. Could do a fiddle if this is not entirely clear.

Comment: There are many solutions to that. 1 is this: position footer absolutely at bottom of 100% height page container. have a content container explicitly `height: 100%` and have it `overflow:scroll` and give it the padding at the bottom.
More solutions will be found just by searching for 'fixed position iOS', it's a common problem

Comment: Jared, if you could provide a fiddle that would be wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry this took so long, got lost in something else! http://jsfiddle.net/jaredkhan/LFHVr/ Think this should do what you want.